# How to use custom TypeConverter in Log4j2's Plugin Attribute?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging, log4j2

**Goal** - What I want to do is I want to make it easier for our devs to be able to look at all the logs for certain users. So if we mention that userId in `logging-config.yml`, then for those specific users, all the logs should be published. We want to do this because it allows us to trace the errors our clients (our userIds) are facing accurately. Also, using Spring Cloud Config Server, we can easily add or remove the user ids from this file, so can make changes at runtime.

**What I tried**

I created a custom filter for Log4j2 so that whenever there is a log statement, the request goes there, we match it against the userIds from `logging-config.yml` which we load into a set, then say proceed or not.

So I created a custom filter like this -

```java
public class UserFilter extends AbstractFilter {
  private final Level maxApplicationLevel;
  private final boolean allowBeforeContextEvaluation;
  private final TenantsLogConfig loggableUsers;

  public UserFilter(final Level maxApplicationLevel,
      final boolean allowBeforeContextEvaluation,
      final UsersLogConfig loggableUsers,
      final Result onMatch,
      final Result onMismatch) {

    super(onMatch, onMismatch);
    this.maxApplicationLevel = maxApplicationLevel;
    this.allowBeforeContextEvaluation = allowBeforeContextEvaluation;
    this.loggableUsers = loggableUsers;
  }

 
  @PluginFactory
  public static UserFilter createFilter(@PluginAttribute("maxApplicationLevel") final Level maxLevel,
      @PluginAttribute("allowBeforeContextEvaluation") final String allowBeforeContextEvaluationStr,
      @PluginAttribute(value = "loggableUsers", defaultClass = UsersLogConfig.class) final UsersLogConfig loggableUsers,
      @PluginAttribute("onMatch") final Result match,
      @PluginAttribute("onMismatch") final Result mismatch) {

    final Level maxApplicationLevel = maxLevel == null ? Level.INFO : maxLevel;
    final boolean allowBeforeContextEvaluation = allowBeforeContextEvaluationStr == null ? Boolean.TRUE :
        Boolean.valueOf(allowBeforeContextEvaluationStr);
    final Result onMatch = match == null ? Result.NEUTRAL : match;

    final Result onMismatch = mismatch == null ? Result.DENY : mismatch;

    return new UserFilter(maxApplicationLevel, allowBeforeContextEvaluation, loggableUsers, onMatch, onMismatch);
  }
```

and my `UserLogConfig` class looks like this -

```java
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonDeserialize
public class UserLogConfig implements Serializable {

  private List<String> userConfigs = new ArrayList<>();

  public boolean contains(String userId) {
    if (!Objects.isNull(this.userConfigs)) {
      return this.getUserConfigs().contains(userId);
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

I also created a converter like this -

```java
@Component
public class UserLogConfigConverter implements Converter<String, UserLogConfig> {

  @Override
  public UserLogConfig convert(String jsonString) {
    String[] userIds = jsonString.split("\\s*,\\s*");
    UserLogConfig usersLogConfig = new UserLogConfig();

    for (String userId : userId) {
      usersLogConfig.getUsersConfig().add(userId);
    }

    return usersLogConfig;
  }

}
```

**Issue I am facing**

If I pass in a string here in log4j2.xml and update the `loggableUsers` to String, then it works

```xml
  <Filters>
    <UserFilter maxApplicationLevel="debug" loggableUsers="123, 456"/>
  </Filters>
```

then it works fine but this is not a scalable solution as we don't want log4j2.xml to be populated with user Ids. So I am trying to pass a yml file

```xml
  <Filters>
    <UserFilter maxApplicationLevel="debug" loggableUsers="./users.yml"/>
  </Filters>
```

And keep `loggableUsers` in java code as `UserLogConfig`. But this throws an error

```
2022-12-26 12:02:26,274 main ERROR Null object returned for UserFilter in Filters.
2022-12-26 12:02:26,814 main ERROR Unable to invoke factory method in class com.axm.platform.logging.util.UserFilter for element UserFilter: java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = 'class com.axm.platform.logging.util.UsersLogConfig' java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = 'class com.axm.platform.logging.util.UsersLogConfig'
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.convert.TypeConverterRegistry.findCompatibleConverter(TypeConverterRegistry.java:105)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.convert.TypeConverters.convert(TypeConverters.java:413)
```

How can I solve for this? I even looked at the [PluginAttribute](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/plugins/PluginAttribute.html) docs but it has no parameter to pass a custom TypeConverter.

Please help, I am stuck at this for last 2 days. Any help would be appreciated :)

So I am trying to pass in a file

Comment: You can also try [`MutableThreadContextFilter`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/filters.html#MutableThreadContextMapFilter), which was introduced exactly for you use-case (bumping the logging for specific users on several servers using Spring Boot Config).

Comment: I couldn't find docs or any post on it. I tried to use it by adding it like this in log4j2.xml file
```<MutableContextMapFilter onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY" operator="or"
    configLocation="http://localhost:5000/logConfigs" pollInterval="300">
  </MutableContextMapFilter>
```
but this doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 1):

The company I works for uses Spring Cloud Configuration to store all the configuration for all our hundreds of services. They all share the same Log4j configuration. We had this exact same requirement. One choice would have been to use the `ThreadContextMapFilter` and then have all applications poll or use SCC's refresh capabilities but that seemed like a very heavyweight solution. So instead, as Piotr mentioned, I created the [MutableThreadContextMapFilter](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/filters.html#MutableThreadContextMapFilter).

The filter works by calling a REST service that contains the RequestContext keys and values you want to enable for debug logging. In our case we store the data in Redis where it will automatically expire after a configured period of time. Since all services share the same Log4j configuration hosted in SCC they all automatically will poll for these changes at the interval specified. As you can see in the documentation, the correct format for configuring the filter is

```
  <MutableContextMapFilter onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="NEUTRAL" operator="or"
    configLocation="http://localhost:8080/threadContextFilter.json" pollInterval="300">
  </MutableContextMapFilter>
```

Note that using DENY on a mismatch means nothing will be logged at all except events that match the data managed by the filter. Typically that isn't what you want as that will suppress error messages.

Log4j DOES NOT provide the implementation of the service being called. You have to implement that. However, Log4j does have a Git repository for samples so I may choose to add a sample service there. I should also point out that the REST call DOES support an AuthorizationProvider, which by default uses BASIC authorization, or you can provide a custom AuthorizationProvider.

If you just want to place the file in SCC you can easily do this by following the [SCC documentation for accessing plain text](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/docs/current/reference/html/#_serving_plain_text). In this case your URL would look something like:

```
https://spring-configuration-server.mycorp.com/${spring.application.name}/default/master/debug.json
```

If, like us, you store your logging configuration in SCC already then it will automatically reuse the credentials configured in the application to access that. I also need to mention that of course the format of the SCC URL is somewhat dictated by how you have your SCC service configured so that it will search the correct location for the file.