# Logger level change for multi-tenant application as well as Package/Class logger level

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, logback, multi-tenant

here we have a use cases, we are working on a web application that will host multiple companies (tenant).

Currently, we have added company-specific log separation using MDC. It will separate the log files per company.

We want the flexibility to change the logger level at runtime for a company (tenant) specific along with package/class logger level change, as we are getting a bulk number of unwanted logs in those files.

Can anyone help me with this?

We have achieved it partially either for the Company or Package level.

· Company-specific logger level change using **Turbo Filter.**

· Package/Class level using **Admin Centre (using Actuator endpoints)**

Our question is if there is any way to change the logger level at run-time for a company-specific along with package/class.

Eg: As Our application is Hosted for two companies ACOMP & BCOMP.

Our requirement is

ACOMP should log at INFO as root logger level, also user can set few packages like **com.test.samplepackage to DEBUG level**.

Similarly,

BCOMP should log at DEBUG as root logger level, also user can set few packages like **com.test.samplepackage to ERROR** level.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: `TurboFilter`s do not exist in Log4j2, they are characteristic to Logback. Did you tag your question correctly? If you are indeed using Log4j2 Core, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74917795/11748454) for a standard filter that can change configuration without reloading the entire logging system.

Comment: Thanks for the response, yes @PiotrP.Karwasz we are using TurboFilters which the characteristic of logback we have already achieved changing configuration per tenant without reloading the entire logging system. But we need to further changing logger level for package/class along with per tenant without reloading the entire logging system.
Let us know if you have any suggestion.