# Sharing Log4j2 configuration between services to ensure same formatting etc.?

Tags: java, logging, microservices, kibana, log4j2

Assume I know how to setup and use Log4j2 for gathering logs from one service.

Now let's consider a case where **logging** is wanted on a **multiple services**, let's say 50 just to have a number. Company also want's to use a **central logging** approach where all logs will be available in a tool, e.g. Kibana.

To make it easier (or even possible) to find relevant data in Kibana, it is necessary to have the same type of information and formatting (**standards**) of the log entries.

**What alternatives are there** to make sure that all (50) services and any new services are configured in the same way?

Probably, the most common way is to have a copy of the log4j2.xml in each service. But I see some cons with this approach.

1. If a change is needed, it needs to be applied to 50 services in 50 different code repositories.
2. For new services, copying often happens from an existing service. If that service already diverged, then you have another service not following the "standards".
3. A copy of log4j2.xml might actually mean more than one, if you have environment specific configurations...

"Externalized log configuration" is there such a thing?
How have you tackled this problem?
Or is it not a real problem? :)

Comment: or you can keep one copy of log4j2.xml in a shared folder accessible by all, then create a symbolic link that points to this log4j2.xml and use that for each of your applications?

Comment: The `log4j2.configurationFile` parameter can be an URL.

Comment: @piotrP.Karwasz Have you experience of that in a multi service environment?

Comment: @experimentunit1998X I guess what Piotr suggested could be seen as "externalized log configuration".

Comment: Check [Ralph's answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74931985/11748454).